# Creating View from Native Surface

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview

I have a NativeActivity where I create a Surface using native code:

```
// Simple example
GraphicBufferAlloc* graphicBufferAlloc = new GraphicBufferAlloc();
BufferQueue* bufferQueue = new BufferQueue( graphicBufferAlloc );
...
Surface* surface = new Surface(bufferQueue);
```

After that, I have to show this Surface in another Activity I have on my app. I can call a Java method and pass this Surface over but I don't know how to show it or embed it in a View.

I looked at the SurfaceView.java, which creates its own Surface, and what it does is: create a custom Window (extending BaseIWindow) and then calls "getWindowSession().relayout" which returns a new surface for the window, which it then caches and uses. Thus, I didn't find a way to set the surface.

There's also, "IWindowSession.addToDisplay" but this takes an IWindow and I'm not sure how or if I can construct one from a Surface.

I must create the Surface from native code, so what I'm looking for is any way to display it in another Activity.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not able to do what you want through public APIs?

Comment: The only piece of code I found that does something similar to what I want is SurfaceView, which uses non-public non-documented APIs. If you know any public API / sample let me know

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to attach an off-screen surface to an existing window. You can follow _[qcamera](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/camera/+/master/QCamera2/HAL/test/qcamera_test.cpp)_: `new SurfaceComposerClient()`->`createSurface()`->`getSurface()`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This apparently does solve the issue of displaying a Surface, I'll try it tomorrow! Thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: I'm not sure how the qcamera gets compiled but when I try to do "createSurface" I get this: "E/SurfaceFlinger(  261): Permission Denial: can't access SurfaceFlinger pid=27626, uid=10012". I'm on KitKat. Will google about it